# How to create the build using Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, hosting, amazon-ec2

I am developing an web app using java/j2ee as middle ware and Mysql 5.1 as database. I have to deploy it on AWS-EC2 server.

My questions are:

1. How do I create the build
2. How do I deploy on ec2 server?

I am using Apache Tomcat-6. Should I use any other server like Apache2 as web-server?

Comment: I don't do Amazon EC2, but is it really not sufficient to just export the project as WAR file the usual way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) to create a Dynamic Web Module project.
2. Use [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/)

That's pretty terse, but you'll need so many more details that it's pointless to list them here. Read the docs, then come back with specific questions :)

Whether you need Apache2 in front of Tomcat depends on your requirements. If you need it you'll know it :) Things that you might want to punt off on Apache2:

- SSL
- Static content
- URL rewriting

Answer (score 2):

If you are just planning to do every thing manually. You should read this manual http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/

Basically,

1. You need to create an AMI instance of platform of your choice. (Win/Unix-based).
2. Configure it with the software that you need. In your case, Tomcat-6 and MySQL-5.1. Configure them. Set Schema etc.
3. Upload your WAR file to the instance and deploy to Tomcat-6.
4. Make sure Tomcat port (8080 or whatever you've configured) is open. You can configure this from AWS console's Security Group setting.
5. Use the instance's Public DNS to access your app. Public DNS can be found from AWS console.

There are many freely available, pre-configured AMI available. Since your setting is one of the most common one. I am sure you will get one and skip `Step#2`.

Comment: I have created the instance and I have configured by installing mysql5.1 and java6 and also tomcat6 server, once I upload the war file to tomcat_catalina/webapp folder how do I connect it to database and how do I transact with the database?